# get the php notice inside a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

Is there a way to get the contents of the PHP notices inside a variable.
I want to render them in my twig template, with some css styles.

I am using wordpress and timber(which in turn uses twig).

Is something similar to what [admin_notice](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) does to admin pages, but for regular pages.

I'm just starting with wordpress so maybe I'm looking at the whole thing wrong. Still I don't want to disable the notices, it does not seem right.

Comment: You mean regular PHP notices? Well first of all, you should try and fix whatever is causing them, as far as possible. And then, have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.track-errors and http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the info. I found [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php#68642) comment which helped me get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

I set my own error handler:

```
set_error_handler('errorHandler');

function errorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
  $data['errno'] = $errno;
  $data['errstr'] = $errstr;
  $data['errfile'] = $errfile;
  $data['errline'] = $errline;
  $data['errcontext'] = $errcontext;
  Timber::render('error.twig', $data);
}
```

And I create a twig template file to render the data nicely

```
{#error.twig#}
<div class="error-box">
  {% if errno %}
  <p class="errno">{{errno}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if errstr %}
  <p class="errstr">{{errstr}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if errfile %}
  <p class="errfile">{{errfile}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if errline %}
  <p class="errline">{{errline}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if errcontext %}
  <p class="errcontext">{{errcontext}}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```